# Boilerplate for independently deployable microservices based on Serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, serverless-framework, serverless, boilerplate

Following the principles of microservices,

```
Defined domain: Each microservice has a defined domain of responsibility (sometimes referred to as a bounded context). The microservice manages this domain itself, without concerning itself about other domains.

Self-contained: Each microservice is a self-contained unit. It may contain multiple components that all work together.

Independently deployable: Each microservice can be built and deployed as an independent entity. Deploying one microservice does not affect another microservice.

Manages data stores: The data store or stores used by each microservice should be contained within the microservice boundary, thereby ensuring that there are no hidden dependencies caused by data stores being shared.

Loosely coupled: Microservices should be loosely coupled, and ideally communication will occur asynchronously using event sourcing or queues.

Highly automated: The build, deployment, and ongoing management of microservices should emphasize automation wherever possible.
```

I am looking for recommendations for the code structure/boilerplate to realize these principles, especially- Independently deployable, loosely coupled, and contained data stores. Using the Serverless framework on AWS. Would be great to have references for boilerplates that have worked well and realize these principles such that deployment order shouldn't matter.

I came across https://github.com/trilom/sls-microservice but this has makefiles. Don't like the idea of having to use them.

Comment: I remember checking this one: https://github.com/brietsparks/guestbook Maybe will help you somehow.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. it isn't using Serverless framework though.  @Marcin I am particularly looking to understand where should the resources/databases/queues be defined such that deployment order shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be just what would serve the purpose right:
https://github.com/zotoio/generator-mono-serverless